# Is the following short exact sequence always split?

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

Is it always true that the following short exact sequence of modules split?

$0\to N\to M\to M/N\to0$

Answer (score 1):

This need not split.  As an example, take $0 \to 2\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$.  More generally, split short exact sequences are precisely those that admit a decomposition $M \approx N \oplus M/N$, which need not be true in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I thought but I think I slightly confused myself by considering the inclusion map of $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{Z}$. Surely this would be a right inverse for the projection $\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: That map is not a homomorphism!  Actually, I'm not even sure which map you're referring to, but there are no such homomorphisms.